# How do `shared_ptr`s achieve covariance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, shared-ptr, covariance

It is possible to copy or construct a `shared_ptr<Base>` from `shared_ptr<Deriver>` (i.e. `shared_ptr<Base> ptr = make_shared<Derived>()`). But as we all know, template classes are not convertible to each other, even if the template arguments are. So how can `shared_ptr`s check if the value of their pointers are convertible and do the conversion if they are?

Comment: If you're talking about the code for `shared_ptr`, then 1- because I don't know how to find it. 2- even if I did find it, reading standard library code is not the best way to learn new programming techniques. Especially for a new comer like me :)

Comment: That's The Black Art of Template Magic Goo.  If you are a newcomer, it may be a bit hard to get your head around.  If you are determined, the best resource is to learn as much as you can about C++ templates, generic programming, and metaprogramming, and read the shared_ptr and make_shared code (since template code is right in its header file).

Comment: I suspect if you just write the code to house the internal pointer in a differently typed template class the compiler will tell you if you made a whoopsie. If the internal pointers are compatible, then the compiler will be fine.

Comment: I think what the OP is asking is "what type does make_shared<Derived> return, and how can that type be used to initialise share_ptr<Base>?"

Comment: @Neil Butterworth. Not really, I am mainly concerned about how shared_ptr classes are convertible to each other. The only reason I used `make_shared` is because I copied and pasted it from my code that I used to test this functionality. I apologize if that mislead anyone about what is the nature of the question

Comment: " I am mainly concerned about how are shared_ptr classes are convertible to each other." - that's effectively  what I said!

Comment: Oops, I guess I misunderstood. I thought you mean't that I was confused about what is the return type of `make_shared`

Comment: @GamefanA - I'm actually surprised nobody has asked the question in the form Mr. Butterworth converted it to. While covariance is the correct word here, it's not a word most C++ programmers use.

Comment: As an aside, this is not covariance, it is implicit conversion.  One of the big problems with shared_ptr is that is does NOT support covariance fully -- specifically, you can't have covariant return types in subclasses if the return type is a shared_ptr instead of a raw pointer.  You can kind-of hack around this problem using raw pointers and shared_from_this, but it is ugly and fragile.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I would say that's more a limitation of covariance of virtual function return types, not with `shared_ptr`. The fact that a `shared_ptr<Derived>` can be "used as a" `shared_ptr<Base>` is a type of covariance.

Comment: @aschepler: its a way that shared_ptrs are unlike pointers. COvariance involves the relationships between the types of two objects, not just one object (hence the CO- prefix), such as the realtionship between the receiver type and the return type with return type covariance.  But this is getting far afield of the question, so should probably be [taken to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/189775) if you want to continue

Comment: @ChrisDodd "_One of the big problems with shared_ptr is that is does NOT support covariance fully_" It's a limit of C++ not `shared_ptr`. There is nothing that makes it impossible or even especially hard to support arbitrary conversions in function return types: instead of adjusting the value of a pointer you would call arbitrary functions.

Comment: @ChrisDodd "_As an aside, this is not covariance, it is implicit conversion_" It's implicit conversion in a given direction. That direction is called "covariant" (on the template parameter); on other types it would make sense to have a conversion "contravariant" on the template parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, specializations of the same class template by default have almost no relationship and are essentially treated like unrelated types.  But you can always define implicit conversions between class types by defining converting constructors (`To::To(const From&)`) and/or conversion functions (`From::operator To() const`).

So what `std::shared_ptr` does is define template converting constructors:

```
namespace std {
    template <class T>
    class shared_ptr {
    public:
        template <class Y>
        shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>&);
        template <class Y>
        shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y>&&);
        // ...
    };
}
```

Though the declaration as shown would allow conversions from any `shared_ptr` to any other, not just when the template argument types are compatible.  But the Standard also says about these constructors ([[util.smartptr]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/util.smartptr.shared#5) and [[util.smartptr.const]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/util.smartptr.shared.const#18) and [util.smartptr.const]/21](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/util.smartptr.shared.const#21)):

> For the purposes of subclause [util.smartptr], a pointer type `Y*` is said to be *compatible with* a pointer type `T*` when either `Y*` is convertible to `T*` or `Y` is `U[N]` and `T` is *cv* `U[]`.
>
> The [...] constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless `Y*` is compatible with `T*`.

Although this restriction could be done in any way, including compiler-specific features, most implementations will enforce the restriction using an SFINAE technique (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error).  One possible implementation:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

namespace std {
    template <class Y, class T>
    struct __smartptr_compatible
        : is_convertible<Y*, T*> {};

    template <class U, class V, size_t N>
    struct __smartptr_compatible<U[N], V[]>
        : bool_constant<is_same_v<remove_cv_t<U>, remove_cv_t<V>> &&
                        is_convertible_v<U*, V*>> {};

    template <class T>
    class shared_ptr {
    public:
        template <class Y, class = enable_if_t<__smartptr_compatible<Y, T>::value>>
        shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>&);

        template <class Y, class = enable_if_t<__smartptr_compatible<Y, T>::value>>
        shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y>&&);

        // ...
    };
}
```

Here the helper template `__smartptr_compatible<Y, T>` acts as a "trait": it has a `static constexpr` member `value` which is `true` when the types are compatible as defined, or `false` otherwise.  Then `std::enable_if` is a trait which has a member type called `type` when its first template argument is `true`, or does not have a member named `type` when its first template argument is `false`, making the type alias `std::enable_if_t` invalid.

So if template type deduction for either constructor deduces the type `Y` so that `Y*` is not compatible with `T*`, substituting that `Y` into the `enable_if_t` default template argument is invalid.  Since that happens while substituting a deduced template argument, the effect is just to remove the entire function template from consideration for overload resolution.  Sometimes an SFINAE technique is used to force selecting a different overload instead, or as here (most of the time), it can just make the user's code fail to compile.  Though in the case of the compile error, it will help that a message appears somewhere in the output that the template was invalid, rather than some error even deeper within internal template code.  (Also, an SFINAE setup like this makes it possible for a different template to use its own SFINAE technique to test whether or not a certain template specialization, type-dependent expression, etc. is or isn't valid.)

Comment: And what is the point of the specialization that has N parameter? Is that used for when unique_ptr holds manages a dynamic array?

Comment: That's to match the specified definition of "compatible". It allows a conversion from pointer to array with specific size to pointer to array with unknown bound, for example, from `std::shared_ptr<int[8]>` to `std::shared_ptr<const int[]>`, even though you can't implicitly convert `int (*)[8]` to `const int (*)[]`.

Answer (score -1):

It works because shared_ptr has (among others) a templated constructor

```
template<typename U> shared_ptr(U * ptr);
```

If U* is not convertible to the shared_ptr's contained type then you will get an error buried somewhere in the shared_ptr implementation.

Comment: Not quite, the OP us asking about passing a shared ptr to derived.  And "participate in overload resolution" wording is 99% chance used here.

Comment: Close, but the `shared_ptr` returned by `make_shared` doesn't match `U*`. It matches a different constructor template `shared_ptr(shared_ptr<U>&&)`. Also, an error "buried somewhere in the implementation" is not likely: the constructor template must not be selected by overload resolution, so error traces should only go that deep, and not into the constructor's actual definition.